# Jinja2 reverse a list

Tags: python, jinja2

Hey i want to reverse the output of the following. Can you help me?

```
{% set page 7 %}
{% for i in range(1,6) %}
    {% set back_link = page - i %}
    {{back_link}}
 {% endfor %}
```

Output: 6 5 4 3 2

Wanted: 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: Why the `page - i` calculation then? Just use `i + 1`.. Or `range(2, 7)` and drop the `+ 1` arithmetic.

Answer (score 29):

You can reverse a list in Jinja2 using the `reverse` filter

```
{% for x in mylist|reverse %}
    {{x}}
{% endfor %}
```

This is compatible with `range` so you could use:

```
{% for i in range(1, 10)|reverse %}
    {{i}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment backwards, you can use range(6,1,-1), the 3rd argument being the increment to use (documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#range)).

Comment: `range()` in Jinja2 is not necessarily the same thing. No mention is made of negative strides in the [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#range). However, I'm assuming it'll work anyway.